# Number of increasing subsequence in an array with sum less than K?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have came across a question where I had to find out the number of increasing subsequences in an array with sum less than K.

**Example:**

Lets say the given array is

```
{5, 12, 7, 9, 10}
```

The increasing subsequences are:

```
{5} , {12} , {5, 12} , {7} , {5, 7}
{9} , {5, 9} , {7, 9} , {5, 7, 9}
{10} , {5, 10}, {7, 10} , {5, 7, 10}, {9, 10}
{5, 9, 10} , {7, 9, 10} , {5, 7, 9, 10}
```

So there is total of 17 increasing subsequences.

Let the value of K be 16, then the number of increasing subsequences with sum less than K becomes 8.

These subsequences are:

```
{5} , {12} , {7} , {5, 7} , {9} , {5, 9} , {10} , {5, 10}
```

So the answer for the above question is 8.

I came up with a solution using dynamic programming and it passed all my test cases. The code is below --

```
int arr[] = {5, 12, 7, 9, 10};
int K = 16;
int sum = 0;
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> cumSumList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(arr.length);

for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  ArrayList<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  li.add(arr[i]);
  cumSumList.add(li);

  if(arr[i] < K)
    sum++;
}

for(int i=1; i<arr.length; i++){
  ArrayList<Integer> li = cumSumList.get(i);
  for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
    if(arr[i] > arr[j]){
      ArrayList<Integer> preLi = cumSumList.get(j);
      for(int idx=0; idx<preLi.size(); idx++){
        int addVal = preLi.get(idx) + arr[i];
        if(addVal < K){
          li.add(addVal);
          sum++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  cumSumList.set(i, li);
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

I would like to know if there is any better/optimal solution for solving this problem? And it would be great if anyone can test this code for their test cases and let me know if it passes yours.

Comment: It'd be more optimal to use BIT structure I believe.

Comment: @kwachmat can you elaborate a bit more or may be refer a link or something. It would really help.